# Router switching of local LAN

Tags: router

Specific logistics of Router internals concerning port blocking on routers that have this capability.

I.e. when you block any port on the Router (not talking about node software firewall rules) does the router block the port only at the WAN (?) or does it also block traffic going from any local node to other local nodes (LAN).

I.e. if the ports are not monitored by a blocking protection listening service or app on the local node, then can you block ports on the router (out, in, or both) but still communicate over same said ports within the local lan?

Say my router is 192.168.1.1 on the local side, and the node at 192.168.1.4 sends a request out to any of TCP and UDP ports 135 ~ 138 or 445 and these ports are blocked on the router, will they still get through to any of the local nodes?

I ask this since I've read in the past on here and elsewhere that "most" consumer routers have a switch for the LAN ports which is connected to routing hardware between said switch and the WAN port. So in essence the router does not control routing of packets directed to another Lan node.

And if so, then of course the catch 22, is this a manufacturing adherence rule or is it just that "most" router do not block the LAN switch also with port blocking?

Comment: no such thing as router switching, please don't invent terminology

Comment: networking terminology is tough enough as it is without people using wrong terms and inventing expressions that they never heard before and that make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is wrong (making your question sound non-sensical). There is no such thing as "node software firewalls" - I wonder if you mean "software running on a computer/non-router device.  There is also a question as to what you mean by router.  From the context of your question, I'm going to assume for the first part you mean a typical home/small office router - generally one with a WAN port and 4 LAN ports.

These routers can be considered as effectively comprising a 2 port router with built in switch for the LAN side (or a 2 port router, with the LAN side connecting to an external switch), so TCP and UDP ports 135 ~ 138 or 445 will not be blocked by the router.

To answer the part of your question about "adherence rule or is it just that "most" router do not block the LAN switch also with port blocking?" it depends on exactly how you define a router -

By the strict definition, a router is a device which forwards packets between networks, thus any router will behave as above.    There are, however, other devices - like "layer 4 switches" and firewalls which can intercept packets between ports - even where the packets are only being switched between ports rather then routed - and can manage/firewall traffic between the ports.  I would not call these device routers.

Further, many routers (even 4 port SOHO ones) can be configured to behave this way - although with substantial difficulty and a performance hit.

It would be fair to say that most routers do not do firewalling on LAN's because most usage cases don't benefit from this functionality and it hugely increases the costs to do it properly. (Instead of using a low powered ARM processor, they might need to look towards an x86 processor for a start, so the hardware will cost 5-15 times as much).

Comment: I would challenge your assertion that there are no "node software firewalls"; That seems like a reasonable description of firewall software running on an endpoint or network "node".  I would also point out that the requester specifically indicated "consumer router" in their post.  I think your answer would be a lot better if you removed all but the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: @Slartibartfast   david is right, there is indeed no such thing as that term he used.   And it doesn't even work as a good description either 'cos Any device on a network can be termed a node(node's aren't just 'end points'), so a better term than he used would be "software firewall" and guess what, that's a standard term. But the term he used is not.   and even his (current) title has wrong terminology.

Comment: @barlop You and I are in agreement that there is such a thing as a "software firewall," which the user was describing and apparently successfully communicating using "wrong terminology."  I'm not sure why you and the answerer are so eager to criticize the word choice of someone trying to learn though.  If there are better options, it can be helpful to offer those options and explain how they are better, but it isn't clear  to me how the sentence "Your terminology is wrong" is helpful to someone.

Comment: @Slartibartfast  I didn't use the phrase "Your[the poster's] terminology is wrong", though I agree it was, and David did suggest in his second sentence that there was no such thing as the term he used. i.e. the poster invented it  So that is a good help for the poster. Also,  I was simply replying to what you wrote.(And i'm not sure that the poster did communicate successfully, I certainly didn't study what he wrote when seeing all that wrong, sometmies -invented- terminology and even in the title. David made a guess at what he means and asked him in a question, having rightly addressed stuff)

Comment: @barlop My goal is improving the answer.  What is your goal in this conversation?  I want to be clear that I don't think the answerer (davdgo) is inaccurate, but I think some of the things the answerer said were less helpful than others for people who are still struggling to learn even the vocabulary associated with computer networks.  I like the answer as a whole; I'm offering a suggestion for improvement.  You are defending the answerers accuracy, which I am not attacking.

Comment: @Slartibartfast not just defending the accuracy, I think the answer says exactly the right thing when it says "There is no such thing as".   That nudges the OP to not make things up. So next time he can describe it or look up the term. But anything other than making terms up. And besides it being a ludicrous description that sounded clever, it was not presented as a description. It was presented as a term(a term that sounded clever). And one has to go to the trouble of googling the term to find out it doesn't exist. (which was more effort than the OP made in getting things right)

Comment: @Slartibartfast  If I were to criticise anything about the answer, it's that the answer didn't also take issue with the title, 'cos that also has wrong terminology, though not as outrageous and deceptive as the other term he made up. He really went star trek when he came up with that second one that david called him out on.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP has the notion of a *socket* - which is an IP address plus a port number together as one unit.  So 192.168.1.99:53 is different than 8.8.8.8:53 and both can exist at the same time without conflicts.

"Blocking ports" can have 2 meanings:

- A packet filter can process traffic on an interface, removing unwanted traffic before letting applications see it.  This can exist on your local system or router, and can exist on one, many, or all interfaces depending on what the packet filter is and how it works.
- If your router is configured to not forward traffic it receives on the Internet-facing interface (WAN) to anywhere in the LAN, some might use the phrasing "blocked port" to refer to that situation.

So:

- Yes, it is possible for your router to receive traffic and process it itself without forwarding back to the LAN.  If you enable remote management on your router, it has a small webserver accepting requests on 80 or 443, processing them itself, and responding without sending anything back on the local LAN.
- Yes, it is possible for your router to be setup to forward incoming traffic on a specific port to a device with a specific IP, but for that device to not respond because a local packet filter is blocking traffic.
- Yes, it is possible for interfaces on your router to not respond to traffic from LAN or WAN due to a packet filter doing its job on traffic first.

Many home routers are Linux based, and Linux has a feature called `iptables` that does packet filtering.  You can modify the `iptables` configuration directly if the router is running `ssh` or `telnet` and has the binaries available, which many do.  The management interface of most routers probably changes `iptables` rules internally according to specific settings.